# Putting two placeholders inside flatMap in Spark Scala to create Array

Tags: scala, apache-spark, placeholder, flatmap

I am applying `flatMap` on a scala array and create another array from it:

```
val x = sc.parallelize(Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
val y = x.flatMap(n => Array(n,n*100,42))
println(y.collect().mkString(","))
1,100,42,2,200,42,3,300,42,4,400,42,5,500,42,6,600,42,7,700,42
```

But I am trying to use `placeholder "_"` in the second line of the code where I create `y` in the following way:

```
scala> val y = x.flatMap(Array(_,_*100,42))
<console>:26: error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 1
       val y = x.flatMap(Array(_,_*100,42))
                              ^
```

Which is not working. Could someone explain what to do in such cases if I want to use placeholder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In scala, the number of placeholders in a lambda indicates the cardinality of the lambda parameters.

So the last line is expanded as

```
val y = x.flatMap((x1, x2) => Array(x1, x2*100, 42))
```

Long story short, you can't use a placeholder to refer twice to the same element.

You have to use named parameters in this case.

```
val y = x.flatMap(x => Array(x, x*100, 42))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use _ placeholder once per parameter. (In your case, flatMap method takes single argument, but you are saying -- hey compiler, expect two arguments which is not going to work)

```
val y = x.flatMap(i => Array(i._1, i._2*100,42))
```

should do the trick.

```
val y = x.flatMap { case (i1, i2) => Array(i1, i2*100,42) }
```

should also work (and probably more readable)